# How to shrink or expand tables depending on size of result of a database query

Tags: excel, vba

I have a oracle database that I read/write data from/to with vba. I would like to build a sort of excel user interface for my db. Currently, my Programm looks like this: I have a table of several columns and 1 row, like this:

```
 --------------------------------------------------------
 | Name | Postal-Code | Favorit Color | Body-Mass-Index | 
 --------------------------------------------------------
 |      |             |               |                 |
 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Depending on a query I trigger from excel, I want to fill this table with data from my db.

**My question:** how do I make the table size (currently 1 row) adapt to the number of rows returned by my db? Furthermore, I would also like to be able to read data from the table (for example after editing it) and sending it to the db. How do I make it so that I select all rows from the table that have data in them?

I should add that I don't know much about excel and vba, so using a table to do all of that was just an idea of mine, if you think there are other things in excel that better fit my desired functionalities please tell me.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd be doing anything other than using the automation that's already in place for importing/linking the data, and then performing post processing (i.e. working with the data that you've just imported). One tip that I always use is to record a macro of the process that you wish to use (so, importing the data, in your case), then examining the code afterwards.

Comment: I am developing the db for a department of the company I am with that don't know anything about databases. So basically I they should not have to concern themselves with how the db is structured and which tables there are. Also, for most db tables, I only want to display certain fields to them. So I want to provide an interface for them such that there workflow looks something like this: Hit load-person button in excel > make some changes to the result > Hit save-changes button. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Though, technically, this isn't the answer you want, I would recommend an [ODBC interface for Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm) to connect your spreadsheet to the data. You'd be able to write your own filter / view / query in Oracle and pull just that data.

To do this, in Excel, switch to the **Developer** ribbon and click **Record New Macro**.  Call the macro something like '*OraDbConnect*' (set other options if you need to).

[image: Record Macro dialog box]

Now switch to the **Data** ribbon and, from the **From Other Sources** drop-down, select **From Data Connection Wizard**.

[image: Connect using the Data Connection Wizard]

Select **ODBC DSN** from the list.

[image: ODBC DSN dialog]

...and select your data table from there.

[image: Select Database and Table dialog]

Now name the connection file that will be used to connect to the database (it would be wise to locate this on a read-only share so that it's available to all users that need it).

[image: Save Data Connection and Finish dialog]

From here you can select just where you want to put your data...

[image: Import Data dialog]

Using the **Properties...** button at the bottom, you can decide if, and how frequently, data is refreshed in your spreadsheet, taking away any need to have complex pieces of VBA code to update it.

From there, I would say, your best bet would be to hide your raw data sheet and create [pivot tables](https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html) or other filtered lists with the data you actually want to show.

Oh!  And don't forget to stop recording your macro!  ;o)